# Alternative to for() loop to compare very large data frame column entries to very large vector list

Tags: regex, r, for-loop, dataframe, grepl

I'm trying to take a data frame, `profiles`, that contains a column of `email` addresses and add a new column made up of the registerable domain part of each email address, `domain`.

I create a vector of the unique `registerable_domains` separately, in a process that is too complex to run against each row in the data frame, the results of  which are a vector that is necessarily smaller than the number of rows in the `profiles` data frame.  I then check to see if each entry in the `registerable_domains` vector appears at the end of each `email` address in the `profiles` data frame, and set the `domain` column entry of the data frame where there is a match.

The code below is reproducible data that you can copy-paste and execute in R, with each line commented to explain what it does.

The `for()` loop does exactly what I want to do: It creates the appropriate entries in the `domain` column of the `profiles` data frame.  The problem is that in this example, the `profiles` data frame has 12 rows and the `registerable_domains` vector has 8 entries.  In the actual data set, the `profiles` data frame has ~ 500,000 rows and the `registerable_domains` vector has ~110,000 entries.  As a result, while the `for()` loop works just fine with a small data set, I need a different approach for a very large data set (my estimate is that this method would take ~75 years to complete on the full data set!).

Your help in transforming this `for()` loop into a time practical operation for a large data set would be greatly appreciated.  I've looked through many other threads, but can't find any answers that address this particular situation (though many other similar, but distinct situations are addressed).  Thanks!

```
# Data frame consisting of a column of 12 emails, and a column of 12 NA entries:

email <- c( "john@doe.com",
            "mary@smith.co.uk",
            "peter@microsoft.com",
            "jane@admins.microsoft.com",
            "luke@star.wars.com",
            "leia@star.wars.com",
            "yoda@masters.star.wars.com",
            "grandma@bletchly.ww2.wars.com",
            "searchfor@janedoe.com",
            "fan@mail.starwars.com",
            "city@toronto.ca",
            "area@toronto.canada.ca");

domain <- c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA);

profiles <- data.frame(email, domain);

profiles; # See what the initial data frame looks like

#                            email domain
# 1                   john@doe.com     NA
# 2               mary@smith.co.uk     NA
# 3            peter@microsoft.com     NA
# 4      jane@admins.microsoft.com     NA
# 5             luke@star.wars.com     NA
# 6             leia@star.wars.com     NA
# 7     yoda@masters.star.wars.com     NA
# 8  grandma@bletchly.ww2.wars.com     NA
# 9          searchfor@janedoe.com     NA
# 10         fan@mail.starwars.com     NA
# 11               city@toronto.ca     NA
# 12        area@toronto.canada.ca     NA

# Vector consisting of email addresses stripped to registerable domain component only, created through a separate process that is too complex to run on each row entry:

registerable_domains <- c(  "doe.com",
                            "smith.co.uk",
                            "microsoft.com",
                            "wars.com",
                            "janedoe.com",
                            "starwars.com",
                            "toronto.ca",
                            "canada.ca");

# Credit to Nick Kennedy for his help with this original solution (http://stackoverflow.com/users/4998761/nick-kennedy)

for (domains in registerable_domains) {                                             # Iterate through each of the registerable domains
    domains_pattern <- paste("[.@]", domains, "$", sep="");                         # Add regex characters to ensure that it's only the end part to deal with nested domain names
    found <- grepl(domains_pattern, profiles$email, ignore.case=TRUE, perl=TRUE);   # Grep for the current domain pattern in all of the emails and build a boolean table for entry locations
    profiles[which(found & is.na(profiles$domain)), "domain"] <- domains;           # Modify profile data table at TRUE entry locations not yet set
}

profiles; # Expected and desired outcome:

#                            email        domain
# 1                   john@doe.com       doe.com
# 2               mary@smith.co.uk   smith.co.uk
# 3            peter@microsoft.com microsoft.com
# 4      jane@admins.microsoft.com microsoft.com
# 5             luke@star.wars.com      wars.com
# 6             leia@star.wars.com      wars.com
# 7     yoda@masters.star.wars.com      wars.com
# 8  grandma@bletchly.ww2.wars.com      wars.com
# 9          searchfor@janedoe.com   janedoe.com
# 10         fan@mail.starwars.com  starwars.com
# 11               city@toronto.ca    toronto.ca
# 12        area@toronto.canada.ca     canada.ca
```

Comment: You can try to use `data.table`'s in place assignment operator `:=`. Your code is making a copy of the whole table on each iteration, that's one of the reasons why it is so slow. You can probably also use fixed patterns instead of PCRE. You can also try looking into `pmatch` function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a solution using `dplyr`

```
library(dplyr)
person <- data_frame(Email = email) %>% 
  mutate(Domain = gsub("^.*@", "", Email)) # everything upto the last @
domain <- person %>% 
  select(Domain) %>% # select the Domain variable
  distinct() %>%  # keep only unique rows
  mutate(Original = Domain) # copy Domain into Original
extra <- domain %>% 
  mutate(Domain = gsub("^[[:alnum:]]*\\.", "", Domain)) %>% # remove all alphanumeric characters upto the first point and overwrite Domain
  filter(grepl("\\.", Domain)) # keep only observations where domain contains at least one point
while (nrow(extra) > 0){
  domain <- bind_rows(domain, extra) #add the rows from extra to domain
  extra <- extra %>% 
    mutate(Domain = gsub("^[[:alnum:]]*\\.", "", Domain)) %>% 
    filter(grepl("\\.", Domain))
}
register <- data_frame(Domain = registerable_domains)
register %>% 
  inner_join(domain, by = "Domain") %>% #join the two table on a common Domain
  inner_join(person, by = c("Original" = "Domain")) # join the resulting table to person where result.Original = person.Domain
```

Comment: This is amazing, @Thierry!  It does exactly what I need.  I've read through your code, and I'm pretty sure I understand what the lines do. But, could I trouble you to add comments that explains what each line does so that I can be sure I understand and learn along the way and adapt it to other similar cases?  Thanks very much!  I've credited you in my source code.

Comment: I've added the comments. Have a look at the vignettes in the `dplyr` package.

Comment: Thanks very much @Thierry!  This makes it very clear.  Much appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

I think that you can reduce your time significantly by going after the easy fruit and by taking some of the operations out of your `for` loop that are easily vectorized.

```
profiles <- profiles %>% mutate(test_domains = sub(".*@", "", email))
```

is easy, and just gives you a new column to use rather than spending time in each iteration.

```
for (d in registerable_domains){
    profiles$domain[d == profiles$test_domains] <- d
}
```

will take the direct matches and should leave you with your present, expensive loop only for those rows that still have `NA`, i.e.,

```
profiles[is.na(profiles$domain)]
```

which will be a proper subset. I don't know how much it saves you and I have to go for now. I shall return to this. Thanks for a well written question with data.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, Shawn Mehan. This does reduce the complexity of the for() loop, but it is still impractically slow as @liborm mentioned because the for() loop makes a copy for each iteration.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is helpful, as I completely change the for-loop philosophy and what it does. Also, I didn't realise if you really need the registerable domains or not. But, my idea is instead of having a list of registerable domains you use the patterns that those domains have and you apply them to your email list.

For example, if the domain ends in `com`, or `ca` then you keep this part and what is on the left, like `searchfor@janedoe.com` becomes `janedoe.com`. If the domain ends in `uk`, then you need this part, you also need `co` and what's before that.

If you manage to spot those patterns you can create a simple function with if-else rules and do something like

```
x = c("luke@star.wars.com",
     "area@toronto.canada.ca",
     "mary@smith.co.uk")

dt = data.frame(x, stringsAsFactors = F)

dt

#                        x
# 1     luke@star.wars.com
# 2 area@toronto.canada.ca
# 3       mary@smith.co.uk

ff = function(x){
  x = strsplit(x, split = "[[:punct:]]")[[1]]

  ifelse(x[length(x)] %in% c("com","ca"),
         paste(x[(length(x)-1):length(x)], collapse = "."),
         paste(x[(length(x)-2):length(x)], collapse = "."))}

dt$v = sapply(dt$x, ff)

dt

#                        x           v
# 1     luke@star.wars.com    wars.com
# 2 area@toronto.canada.ca   canada.ca
# 3       mary@smith.co.uk smith.co.uk
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion @AntoniosK.  I do need the registerable domains part and the identification of the patterns is a complex problem that changes as new top-level-domains are added.  I've adapted a separate PHP script to do that part for me, which created the vector in the first place.